# Import multiple modules with a single statement

Tags: python

There are multiple modules I use on a daily basis, and importing all of them every time I want to use them is quite bothersome.

I was hoping for something such as this

```
#essentials.py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
etc etc
```

Then in something else, I could do:

```
import essentials
r = requests.get(example) #Requests is not defined here, as I have not imported it
soup  = BeautifulSoup(r, 'lxml')
```

Comment: `from essentials import *` could be an approach. However, I find it saner to explicitly list imports as needed. It's not that hard. If you use a decent IDE it can add the `import` statement semi-automatically the first time you mention the module name.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
from essentials import *
```

This will put all the names in `essentials.py` into the namespace of the module, if this is done in the top-level of the module.

So you can do

```
from essentials import *
r = requests.get(example)
soup  = BeautifulSoup(r, 'lxml')
```

Take a look at [the official documentation for reference](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#).